# Flutter generated files are not getting ignored in .gitignore

Tags: flutter, gitignore

When I build a Flutter app, some files are automatically generated. I just simply want to ignore them in git. But it stays even if I added them to .gitignore.

OS: Windows 11

The files:

```
linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.h
linux/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake
macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift
windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.h
windows/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake
```

I tried adding followings in my .gitignore file.

```
linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
linux/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.h
linux/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake
macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift
windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.cc
windows/flutter/generated_plugin_registrant.h
windows/flutter/generated_plugins.cmake

linux/flutter/*
macos/Flutter/*
windows/flutter/*

*generated*
*Generated*
```

All didn't help. I still see them in git changes.

Comment: is your .gitignore file under the root folder?

Comment: For my case(VS Code) it is really get ignored but the git extension shows I've to add them. While I try to add them (using icon, not command), there is nothing to commit. I kept using discard changes before pulling/switching between branches.

Comment: Yes, it is in the root folder. I am using Android Studio btw. I am having a hard time because I have to deselect these seven files before making any commit.

Comment: Even if you kept the seven files away from committing and pushing, I would suggest you to clear the git cache with `git rm -r cache .` But before, remember to commit everything you've changed since last commit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are already tracked in git you'll need to remove them from version control before git will ignore them.

1. Delete the files and commit the removals
2. Add the file paths or patterns to `.gitignore`

Comment: Thank you so much Bart!! It really was an inconvenient developer experience for me for months. I resolved it as you instructed.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy to have helped.